# Hi, I just installed requests with pip but I can't import it

Tags: python, python-requests

For example my Code is:

```
import requests  
r = requests.get('https://www.python.org')  
r.status_code
```

And the Result is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Users\Till\workspace\firstproject\Learning_python\Web_crawler.py", line 6, in <module>
    import requests  
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
    from .models import Request, Response, PreparedRequest  
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 856
    http_error_msg = u'%s Client Error: %s for url: %s' % (self.status_code, reason, self.url)
                                                      ^                                                          
SyntaxError: invalid Syntax
```

Comment: Note that the `^` indicates the first location where the Python parser got confused and found something it did not expect; in this case a string literal following the name `u`. Please don't try to interpret that as the `'` character being the cause of the syntax error. Leave the traceback unchanged.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Requests requires Python 3.3 or newer. It doesn't work on Python 3.2 as that version doesn't support the required `u'...'` compatibility syntax for string literals.

From the [`requests` documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/#supported-features):

> Requests officially supports Python 2.6–2.7 & 3.3–3.5, and runs great on PyPy.

Note that 3.2 is rather.. ancient. You really want to upgrade to a more recent Python 3 revision.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as issue is that Requests require Python-3.3 or higher so you will need to upgrade your Python. I noticed you are on windows so follow this link to download the installer for latest stable Python-3.5.2 (https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.2/python-3.5.2-webinstall.exe).

Also, look into using virtualenvs(https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/). They are a great way to insulate the python packages you have installed and you can set it up using for different projects that may have different requirements.