# Syntax Errors when trying to use pip3 on Debian

Tags: python, syntax, pip, debian, syntax-error

I've been trying to use pip on debian, but I keep getting syntax errors which suggest it's clashing with python2, but I've uninstalled all python packages and reinstalled python3 by itself. The error still occurs when the only packages I've installed are python3 and python3-pip.

```
root@CONQUISTADOR:~# pip --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==9.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 337, in load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2280, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1990, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.2.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
from pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import DependencyWarni                                                                             ng
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.2.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
from .models import Request, Response, PreparedRequest
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py3.2.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/models.py", line 856
http_error_msg = u'%s Client Error: %s for url: %s' % (self.status_code, reason, self.url)                                   
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is on debian 7.9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using python 3.2. You need to upgrade it to at least python 3.3 for some packages such as [requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38957513/hi-i-just-installed-requests-with-pip-but-i-cant-import-it) to install.